# Making small minigame C# and custom framework

Tags: c#, xna

Hello people from stackoverflow!,

i am making a small mini game with a custom framework that works with C# and it's somehow based on XNA(in case you can help me, write it xna-way).

Basically i have a couple of circles, let's say 6, i need to "mark" the first one, after that after clicking the transparent one i need to create another one, but upon clicking the last one marked it will go back and remove one (the picture is easier to understand).

i will upload a small image to illustrate (it's hard to explain, i am not a native english-speaker).

i believe i have to use an array and mark it depending on the order, but i'm still kindda lost :(

Sorry if it's too much to ask, i have been trying all day!
ps: it's a single row!
Image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbsuI.jpg

Update: this is what 'ive got so far. and now it's working!!

```
 private void CircleController()
{
    Debug.Log("Marked circles:" + markedCircles);
    Debug.Log("Sum Circles: " + sumCircle);

    List<CGameObject> mArray = CCircleManager.inst().getGameObjectList();

    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.Count; i++)
    {
        CCircle aCircle = mArray[i] as CCircle;

        if (aCircle.getOrder() < sumCircle)
        {
            aCircle.setMarked(true);

        }
        else
        {
            aCircle.setMarked(false);

        }


    }


    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.Count; i++)
    {

        CCircle aCircle = mArray[i] as CCircle;
        CCircle initCircle = mArray[0] as CCircle;

        if (aCircle.getOrder() == sumCircle)
        {
            aCircle.setPostSelected(true);
        }

        if (aCircle.getOrder() != sumCircle)
        {
            aCircle.setPostSelected(false);
        }
        if (aCircle.collides(mPointer) && CMouse.firstPress() && !aCircle.isMarked())
        {
            markedCircles++;
            sumCircle++;

        }
        if (aCircle.collides(mPointer) && CMouse.firstPress() && aCircle.isMarked())
        {
            markedCircles--;
            sumCircle--;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] and show, in a minimal way, *what* you have been trying.  Otherwise you're going to get downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: i didn't backuped the class but i am goint to edit and try to re do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might do to simply have an integer `circlesMarked` storing how many circles are in view. If `circlesMarked == 0` then display your first row (in the linked image), if `circlesMarked == 1` then display one marked circle with one transparent circle to its right, and so on. This can be done with a `for` loop.

Store the location of the last (right-most) marked circle (if applicable) and the location of the transparent circle, so that you know where to handle clicks. Then, just add or subtract `1` from `circlesMarked` depending on where they click. XNA's `Render` method should update the view accordingly, and you have a variable containing the number of circles currently marked.

Comment: i'll try it, it's a single line actually

Comment: Is the transparent circle a new sprite or another circle?

Comment: Either should be fine. I think XNA lets you set the opacity, so you could probably use the existing sprite if you wanted.

Comment: Hey i fixed it, thanks! the solution is in the main post.